# Excel-data extraction from sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one requirement to grab data from excel .

I have one excel file with two sheet lets call it as `A` & `B`.

`A` has some entry

[image]

and `B` has some entry

[image]

Now my requirement is on sheet `A`:

- I need sheet `B` col `Cost_Apr` (which is matchings with same entry on Sheet `A`
- I need those entry as well which is not matching

Is there any formula. I know manually we can do after applying `VLOOKUP` but I need a better solution.